# Rails: How can I validate my records so that no two records are the same?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, csv, rails-activerecord

I've been trying to get the `validates_uniqueness_of` to work for my database.  I pull in records from a CSV file, and I want to make sure that I record them all but when I check the next time I don't want to save them all again if they're just duplicates.

**Example Object**

```
PlayerStats {session_date, uniform_number, last_name, first_name, throws, throws_caught, throws_dropped, intercepted_throws, defended_throws }
```

**Example Records**

```
2013-01-01, 11A, Jacobsen, Mike, 11, 4, 7, 0 0
2013-01-01, 11A, Jacobsen, Mike, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1
```

I want to keep both of these records, but when I try to validate like so...

```
validates_uniqueness_of :uniform_number, :scope => [:session_date, :last_name]
```

this will only keep for instance the first record and consider the second a duplicate.
I would like to have it where when the second record goes through a save attempt it will save the second record also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are only validating uniqueness of three fields and not all fields. You should add all your fields to `:scope`. But that will not be very good performance wise if you have a table with too many rows. I would suggest you generate a token out of all the fields you want to validate uniqueness of and add uniqueness validation on token. Going this route you have to add one more column to your table to store the calculated token. Don't forget to add unique index on the column to get the optimum performace. After that following should do the trick:

```
before_validate :generate_unique_token

# assuming you named your slug column `unique_token`
validates :unique_token, uniqueness: true

private
# add all fields you want to validate uniqueness on
UNIQUE_FIELDS = [:uniform_number, :session_date, :more_fields] 
def generate_unique_token
  return if self.unique_token.present?
  token_string = ''

  # additional comma is to ensure that [1, 10]  and [11, 0] don't get treated as same input
  UNIQUE_FIELDS.each {|field| token_string << self.send(field).to_s << ','} 

  self.unique_token = token_string
end
```

This string can get big, but you will not get any false collisions. If you want to control the size of the generated token you can do it like following:

```
def generate_unique_token
  token_string = ''
  UNIQUE_FIELDS.each {|field| token_string << self.send(field).to_s << ','} 
  self.unique_token = compress_token(token_string)
end

def compress_token(token_string)
  # you can further compress the token by encoding it in base 62/64
  ::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(token_string)
end
```

But beware, the later solution can have rare false collisions.

Comment: Tried your method but it appears nothing is getting inserted into the database, so I'm trying to debug that now.  Also I had tried putting all fields into the scope but for some reason that didn't work before... not sure why.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure what I really changed but looks to be working with your method.  Thanks a lot for the explanations too!